# How can I make a limited-dynamically-sizing parent div contain two variable-size child divs, each of which is independently auto-scrollable?

Tags: css, html

**Consider the following structure:**

```
<div id="PARENT_DIV">
    <div id="LEFT_CHILD_DIV">

    </div>
    <div id="RIGHT_CHILD_DIV">

    </div>
</div>
```

**Requirements for PARENT_DIV:**

- **PARENT_DIV** will be placed in front of all other GUI elements via `z-index`.
- **PARENT_DIV** should expand both horizontally and vertically based on the variable sizes of **LEFT_CHILD_DIV** and **RIGHT_CHILD_DIV**, but only to a certain point.  E.g., I need to be able to set the equivalent of `max-width` and `max-height` on **PARENT_DIV**.  For vertical height, **PARENT_DIV** should expand up to the height of the taller child div (but still only up to `max-height`), and the other child should float to the top.
- I need to be able to arbitrarily place **PARENT_DIV** on the screen by various means (e.g., `top: Ypx; left: Xpx;` **or** `top: Y%; left: X%;` **or** `top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(50%, 50%);`, etc.).

**Requirements for each of **LEFT_CHILD_DIV** and **RIGHT_CHILD_DIV**:**

- **LEFT_CHILD_DIV** and **RIGHT_CHILD_DIV** should each expand both horizontally and vertically based on their content, but only to a certain point.  E.g., I need to be able to set the equivalent of `max-width` and `max-height` independently on **LEFT_CHILD_DIV** and **RIGHT_CHILD_DIV**.
- **LEFT_CHILD_DIV** and **RIGHT_CHILD_DIV** should always be side-by-side, regardless of their capped widths.
- **LEFT_CHILD_DIV** and **RIGHT_CHILD_DIV** should each/independently vertically scroll their content when they can no longer grow taller (capped by either their `max-height` rules or **PARENT_DIV**'s `max-height` rule, whichever comes into effect first.

Please see [this example Photoshop mock-up](https://preview.ibb.co/fYjAGK/LS_Layout_for_Stack_Overflow.jpg) for a visual of what I'm trying to accomplish.  I have not been able to find a CSS-related tutorial on how to accomplish exactly the above.  I've found bits and pieces, but they do not work when combined together.  I've tried numerous CSS combinations/variations on rules like `display`, `overflow`, `box-sizing`, `position`, etc., and am not achieving any success.  How can I accomplish the above requirements using CSS?

I can accomplish this with JavaScript, but would like to avoid scripting if possible, and do this in pure-CSS way.

Comment: I see a list of requirement and not a question ... and if you tried numerous CSS combination you need to show us

Comment: The question, as shown in the title and again in the 2nd-to-last paragraph, is, how do I accomplish the requirements via CSS?  I scrapped the numerous previous attempts (which would be far too numerous to post here) because none of them worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use flexbox like this:

```css
#PARENT_DIV {
  position:absolute;
  top:50px;
  left:150px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-flex;
  max-height: 200px;
  max-width: 300px;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

#LEFT_CHILD_DIV {
  border: 1px solid green;
  max-width: 180px;
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
}

#LEFT_CHILD_DIV>div {
  height: 200px;
  width:200px;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  animation:change 2s infinite alternate linear;
}

#RIGHT_CHILD_DIV {
  border: 1px solid orange;
  max-width: 80px;
  max-height: 50px;
  overflow: auto;
}

#RIGHT_CHILD_DIV>div {
  width: 200px;
  height:300px;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  animation:change 2s 1s infinite alternate linear;
}

@keyframes change{
  to{width:5px;height:20px;}
}
```

```html
<div id="PARENT_DIV">
  <div id="LEFT_CHILD_DIV">
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div id="RIGHT_CHILD_DIV">
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, Temani!  I used flexbox years ago (different names back then, but was the same concept).  I stopped using it because its behavior was erratic and unpredictable across various browsers/versions, and many browsers/versions didn't support it at all.  Since you gave this answer, I have revisited flexbox and it seems to have come a very long way in terms of browser support and implementation.  I will use it.  In the course of revisiting flexbox I also found the [link](Flexy Boxes tool), which is great for getting up to speed quickly. And +1 for simulating real-world behavior via animations!